# Run react native project into samsung device

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

last week i start learn `React Native` and used android emulate to run and debug the application when i finished my first project i need to run the app to android deivce and go to react native page and done all steps  [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html/) i got the same error every time like this

[image]

how i can solve this problem ? its very important for me , thanks all :)

**Edit**
after i add my ip address to dev menu into project in my device and reload JS i got this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Android device needs to connect to the build server running on your laptop. Assuming that both your phone and the laptop are on the same network, fetch the laptop's IP address and key it in to the settings menu, invoked by launching the Developer Menu.

More details here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

Comment: i done this steps and when fetch the laptop ip address and but it into dev menu , i got another error , "The development server returned response error code:404" do you have any idea for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think You should have to same network on both devices mobile and machine.

Comment: have you update the IP address after connecting on same network ?

Comment: iam using ubuntu 16.04 , and i add the ip address then i got this error , 'the development server returned response error code : 404 '

Comment: could you please create new project and try then. or read the documentation carefully.

Comment: thank you i read the documentation and do all steps , i will edit my question here to show you the new error

Comment: yeah great.. sure

Comment: are you using the html in your app.

Comment: no , i use react native , and i create  new project and dont modify it ,

Comment: Please make sure you have the packager started & running in the correct folder, looks like you are trying to run a project whereas the packager runs in the folder of the previous one. and one more question check the terminal that if have already running the server